# Is it allowed to associate specific file types to installed UWP app?

Tags: shell, uwp

I have a PDF viewer which is an UWP app, is it possible to register to Windows platform so that this app can be launched by Windows when Desktop App calls shell API (ShellExecute with open verb) to open the PDF document?

Comment: try to change the default app for PDF in the Settings, not sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add a file type association in the AppxManifest. If you're using Visual Studio there is a graphical editor that will guide you (open the file `package.appxmanifest`)